# inequality on simple proccesses

Tags: integration, probability-theory, inequality

I'm going trough my script and I'm not able to understand a step that involve an inequality.

Let $\pi_n: o=t_0^n<...<t^n_{k_n}=T$ with $|\pi_n|\to0$

Let $\phi^n(s)=\sum_{i=0}^{k_n-1}t_i\mathbb 1_{(t_i,t_{I+1})}(s)$

The following step is that one that I would like to understand:

$$\int_0^T(\phi^n(s)-s)^2ds \le |\pi_n|^2T$$
This step allow me to conclude that $ |\pi_n|^2T \to 0$

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, $|\pi_n| = \sup_{i=0, ..., k_n-1} |t^n_{i+1}-t_n^i|$, or something like it. 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^T (\phi^n(s) - s)^2 ds &= \sum_{i=0}^{k_n-1}\int_{t_i^n}^{t_{i+1}^n} (\phi^n(s)-s)^2 ds\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{k_n-1}\int_{t_i^n}^{t_{i+1}^n} (t_i^n -s)^2 ds\\
& \leq \sum_{i=0}^{k_n-1}\int_{t_i^m}^{t^n_{i+1}} |\pi_n|^2 ds \\
&= |\pi_n|^2 T.
\end{align*}

Comment: I have two questions: 1) why can you take the sum outside the square, the fact that is squared does not imply a double summation? 2) why I can say that $t_i^n-s\le |\pi_n|$? it seems to me that s is not a point of the partition so what ensure that the maximum distance between two point of the partition is larger than $t_i^n-s$?

Comment: (1) I am not taking the sum outside the square, I am using linearity of integrals $\int_a^b + \int_b^c = \int_a^c$ and the fact that $\phi^n(s) = t^n_i$ for $s \in [t_i^n, t_{i+1}^n)$ (or can be defined as such). (2)  $s$ is not a general point, $s \in [t^n_i, t^n_{i+1})$, so $0 \leq s - t_i^n \leq t_{i+1}^n - t_i^n \leq |\pi^n|$, and (3) why did you accept (and presumably upvote) an answer you don't understand?